# Url direct in PyQt4 webview

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qnetworkrequest

I would like to know the best way to do a url redirect in pyqt webview. The following is an extract of my code. I originally did it with `web.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))` however I receive the following warning:

```
content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Use QNetworkRequest::setHeader() to fix this problem. When I try use the QNetworkRequest class nothing happens.

```
class qt:

    def __init__(self):
        self.app=QApplication(sys.argv)

    def q(self, meth, url):
        t=meth
        url=url
        self.web=QWebView()
        self.web.load(QUrl(url))
        self.web.loadFinished.connect(t)
        self.web.show()
        self.app.exec_()

class run:

    def __init__(self,url):
        self.n=qt()
        self.n.q(self.method,url)

    def method(self):
        nurl="https://www.newurl.com"
        #self.n.web.load(QtCore.QUrl(nurl))
        req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest()
        req.setRawHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        self.nam = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.nam.get(req)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url='https://www.oldurl.com/'
    i=run(url)
```

Comment: When you call method ?, please provide a [mcve], on the other hand do not use time.sleep, remove it.

Comment: thanks have updated the sample code